# Populate combox with mapped drives

Tags: winforms, powershell

Trying to populate a combo box with mapped drive letters (name) and FQDN (Root).  I think I have most of the code but the combo box entries includes coded entries.

I'm not only curious about how to fix this but why the results are entered this way.  Running this via command line does not display results this way.

NOTE: I'm also using a function to populate the combo box.

**Code to retrieve mapped drives**

```
Load-ComboBox -ComboBox $cboDomain -Items (Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Select-Object name, @{ n = "Root"; e = { if ($_.DisplayRoot -eq $null) { $_.Root } else { $_.DisplayRoot } } })
```

**Function to load combo box**

```
function Load-ComboBox{
Param (
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox]$ComboBox,
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Items,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$DisplayMember,
    [switch]$Append
)
if(-not $Append)
{
    $ComboBox.Items.Clear() 
}
if($Items -is [Object[]])
{
    $ComboBox.Items.AddRange($Items)
}
elseif ($Items -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable])
{
    $ComboBox.BeginUpdate()
    foreach($obj in $Items)
    {
        $ComboBox.Items.Add($obj)   
    }
    $ComboBox.EndUpdate()
}
else
{
    $ComboBox.Items.Add($Items) 
}
$ComboBox.DisplayMember = $DisplayMember}
```

The entries look like;
@{Name=C; Root=C:}
@Name=S; Root=\\server\share}

I want it to look like;
C<-tab->C:\
S<-tab->\\server\share

*Sorry couldn't figure out how to actually insert tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are sending **Objects** to the function (Select-Object returns objects), and not an array of tab separated strings, the function would work if you call it like this:

```
$drives = (Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | ForEach-Object { 
    $root = if ($_.DisplayRoot -eq $null) { $_.Root } else { $_.DisplayRoot }
    # output a tab-separated string that gets collected in the $drives variable
    "$($_.Name)`t$root"
})

Load-ComboBox -ComboBox $cboDomain -Items $drives
```

Hope that explains

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Theo.  
Perfect.